# Is it possible to intercept JUnit test methods?

Tags: java, spring, junit, proxy, interceptor

I would like to intercept JUnit test methods. I already have interceptor that prepares context for the test. I don't want to duplicate the code in my interceptor.

Is it possible to tell SpringJUnit4ClassRunner to use myTest() instance of the test class? Something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class })
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    public MyTest myTest() {
        final ProxyFactoryBean proxy = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        proxy.setBeanFactory(this.beanFactory);
        proxy.setTarget(this);
        proxy.addAdvice(this.myInterceptor);

        return (MyTest) proxy.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: That example does not solve my problem: it does not provide me with an interceptor that would intercept all test methods.

Comment: Clarify your question: Do you need something like a JUnit MethodRule that intercepts all call to test methods annotated with @Test? Do you want a way to wrap all *beans* in Spring to add functionality to the Spring beans? Your title and description and example tell three different stories.

Comment: Also consider Mockito spy(). Maybe better explain what your ultimate goal is. In any case using the test class itself as a Spring Bean sounds like a wrong approach. Keep your Junit classes and you Spring beans separate. Use Spring beans only for things related to your application domain.

Comment: Yes, something like MethodRule, but invoking my existing interceptor. I don't want to duplicate the code in my interceptor.